# Why does original paper introducing DBSCAN state it takes only one input parameter?

Tags: clustering, algorithms

I am reading about the DBSCAN clustering algorithm from the [original paper by Ester et al](https://www.aaai.org/Papers/KDD/1996/KDD96-037.pdf). In this paper, the authors state in the abstract, the introduction, and the conclusion that their algorithm takes only one input parameter, and furthermore that it "supports the user in determining an appropriate value for [the parameter]." However throughout the rest of the paper there are clearly two parameters, which they call *MinPts* and *Eps*. This is also the case in any other presentation of the algorithm, including the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN), which cites *the original paper*.

I found this very confusing when reading the paper. My question is: What? Is this an error that just happened appeared many times in the paper? If this really is just a typo, how has it not been noticed when the paper has been cited over 7000 times? Do I not understand the meaning of "input parameter"? Do I not understand the algorithm?

Comment: Read the paper (not Wiki) again. IIRC they suggest minpts=4 because higher values didn't seem to change much. It is fairly common to exclude parameters with default values from the count. IMHO, it is a feature to have more parameters.

Comment: Ah, duh. I guess to me,  suggesting a value for a parameters isn't the same as it not existing. If you like you can make that comment an answer and I will accept it.